# how to remove xml namesapce with SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I need to do xml transformation with SAX parser, for that i need to remove namespace from the xml. Since we are handling with huge xml, i need to use SAX parser.

sample input xml:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
 xmlns:ns2="http://www.google.com/generation/type">
    <ns2:meta>
        <gender xmlns="" xmlns:ns5="http://www.google.com/generation">M</gender>
        <dateOfBirth xmlns="" xmlns:ns5="http://www.google.com/generation">1976-07-19</dateOfBirth>
        <ns2:languageRef>ENG</ns2:languageRef>
    </ns2:meta>
    <root>
```

with the help of SAX parser, i need the below output.

```
       <root>
            <meta>
                <gender>M</gender>
                <dateOfBirth>1976-07-19</dateOfBirth>
                <languageRef>ENG</languageRef>
            </ns2:meta>
        <root>
```

Thanks in advance..

The code which i tried,

i tried with XMLFlterImpl,

```
XMLReader xr = new XMLFilterImpl(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()) {

  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.contains(":")) {
      String[] data = data = qName.split(":");


      super.startElement(uri, localName, data[1], atts);
    } else {
      super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);
    }
  }
```

this removes the element name prefix(namespace), but not sure how to remove the namespace attributes

Comment: are you required to use SAX or you can use StAX instead?

Comment: With sax parser only

Comment: are you allowed to use StAX to write XML output, since SAX does not write XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Ok, with direction from comments from @MichaelKay, here is my updated answer.

*To remove namespace from tags:*

As suggested in his answer, the `startElement` should have `""` in place of `uri`. What about *Ending tag ?:*
In your question I don't understand why you want `ns2` for ending `meta` tag particularly when you want to remove it for the starting tag. 
I assume you want it to be removed for ending tag too. So similarly `endElement` should also have `""` in place of `uri`.

*Filter XMLNS attributes:*

You could create a new `AttributesImpl`. Then go through the list of attributes and check if the `QName` starts with `xmlns`, if not add it to the `AttributesImpl` and use it in the `startElement` as :

`super.startElement("", localName, data[1], aImpl);`

Also note that as per @MartinHonnen, yes the attributes' `uri` should also be "" and also the `qName` should be without prefix as with elements. But if you want to keep the attributes' names as such ( which I don't think you want to ) you can just keep `atts.getQName(i)` as is.

Also set Namespaces feature to false like :

`xf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);`

**Code :**

```
try {

   InputSource file = new InputSource("filterns.xml");

   XMLFilterImpl xf = new XMLFilterImpl(
           XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()) {
       @Override
       public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
           String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

               AttributesImpl aImpl = new AttributesImpl();

                int l = atts.getLength();
                for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {

                    if (atts.getQName(i) != null
                            && atts.getQName(i).startsWith("xmlns")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        String aQName = atts.getQName(i);
                        String[] s = aQName.split(":");
                        if (s.length > 1) {
                            aQName = s[1];
                        }

                        aImpl.addAttribute("",
                                atts.getLocalName(i), aQName,
                                atts.getType(i), atts.getValue(i));
                    }

                }

                String[] s = qName.split(":");
                if (s.length > 1) {
                    super.startElement("", localName, s[1], aImpl);
                } else {
                    super.startElement("", localName, qName, aImpl);
                }

       }

       @Override
       public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
              String qName) throws SAXException {

              String[] s = qName.split(":");
              if (s.length > 1) {
                 super.endElement("", localName, s[1]);
               } else {
                  super.endElement("", localName, qName);
                 }

       }

       @Override
       public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri) {
       }

   };

   xf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
   SAXSource src = new SAXSource(xf, file);

   StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
   TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
           .newInstance();
   Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
   transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
   transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,"yes");
   transformer.transform(src, new StreamResult(stringWriter));

   String xml = stringWriter.toString();
   System.out.println(xml);

} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's a horrible approach - you're making no attempt to escape special characters in the output! Generally, serializing by hand is almost as serious an offence as parsing by hand. In some ways it's worse, because other people will have to deal with the invalid output you create.

Comment: @MichaelKay OK I get it, I am curious how do I have to escape special characters if I ever have to do it. Also I am just appending whatever I get from the parser right ? What am I missing ?

Comment: It's not difficult to do it right, though an awful lot of people seem to fail to do it properly, but the best approach is to use an existing serialization library. For example, a common approach is to do an identity transform to a StreamResult.

Comment: I guess, for consistency, as namespace attributes are stripped, you need to make sure that the attributes you pass on are also stripped of their namespace, so instead of `aImpl.addAttribute(atts.getURI(i), ...)` you rather need `aImpl.addAttribute("", ...)` and for the third argument, the qName you probably need to perform the same change as for the qName of an element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I edited the answer. yes I don't believe atts should keep their namespaces if the elements' are stripped. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I also had to set the feature `namespaces` to false, it ignore namespace while parsing attributes. `xf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);`

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
super.startElement(uri, localName, data[1], atts);
```

you are passing the original namespace URI unchanged to the output. You need to get rid of it, use:

```
super.startElement("", localName, data[1], atts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually attempts to remove namespaces to perform a "transformation" is a sign of lack of understanding of how to handle XML but in general if you use SAX and want to alter the processed XML you can implement a filter https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLFilter.html, starting with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/XMLFilterImpl.html as a base clase and overriding the methods where you expect and want to strip namespaces.

Comment: i tried XMLFilterImpl, added the code which i tried

Comment: can you help me in removing the namespace attributes

Comment: I am not deeply familiar with the SAX API, it looks like you should use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/Attributes2Impl.html#Attributes2Impl-- to construct new attributes from the one your handler receives, where you of course make sure the new attributes don't have the namespace the original ones have. You will have to try a bit but I am sure you can work it out.

Comment: I am tried, but the newly created attributes are not overriding the existing. Thanks for your comment

Comment: By default (@MartinHonnen) namespace declarations are not passed across as attributes. But there's a configuration property to control this, so it may be worth checking that this is set correctly. However, the main problem is that the first parameter of startElement - the namespace URI part of the element name - is being passed through unchanged.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I was wondering if an XMLFilter written as an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet and created from `com.saxonica.config.StreamingTransformerFactory` and `.newXMLFilter()` would do the task in a pure streaming way?

Comment: Yes that should be possible

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of what can be done with VTD-XML. Let me know if there is any question.

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;
public class removeNS {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws VTDException, IOException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\ns.xml", true))
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        for (int i=0;i<vn.getTokenCount();i++){

            int t = vn.getTokenType(i);
            switch(t){

                case VTDGen.TOKEN_STARTING_TAG:
                    stripElementPrefix(i,vn,xm);
                    break;
                case VTDGen.TOKEN_ATTR_NAME:
                    stripAttrPrefix(i,vn,xm);
                    break;
                case VTDGen.TOKEN_ATTR_NS: 
                    xm.removeAttribute(i);
                default:
            }
        }
        xm.output("d:\\xml\\nsOut.xml");
    }

    public static void stripAttrPrefix(int i, VTDNav vn, XMLModifier xm) throws VTDException{
        //get the offset and length of localname part of starting tag
        int os1 = vn.getTokenOffset(i);
        int len = vn.getTokenLength(i);
        if ((len>>16)!=0){
            int temp1 = (0xffff & len) - (len>>16)-1;
            int temp2 = os1 + (temp1);
            xm.removeContent(temp1, temp2);
        }

        //int offset=
    }

    public static void stripElementPrefix(int i, VTDNav vn, XMLModifier xm) throws VTDException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        //int os1 = vn.getTokenOffset(i)
        int os1 = vn.getTokenOffset(i);
        int len = vn.getTokenLength(i);
        if ((len>>16)!=0){
            int temp1 = (0xffff & len) - (len>>16)-1;
            int temp2 = os1 + (len>>16)+1;
            String s = vn.toRawString(temp2, temp1);
            System.out.println(s);
            vn.recoverNode(i);
            xm.updateElementName(s);
        }
    }

}
```